# Manual transmission kicks in and out of gear while driving

Tags: subaru, manual-transmission, impreza

1999 Subaru Impreza Outback Sport - I put it in gear, start driving, then it starts kicking in and out of gear. It does this in all gears and reverse. Is it the transmission or an electrical problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: With a bit of luck the shift linkage or engine mounts are  worn/loose, else the gearbox needs an overhaul (expensive). How does the shift lever feel?

Answer (score 1):

Try driving it as gently as you possibly can, like there's a vat of boiling soup on the dashboard.

If that prevents or reduces the transmission from popping out of gear, you can suspect the engine and/or transmission mounts have torn.

This allows the drivetrain to shift, while the gear shift lever is held by a joint in the body.  This causes the car to "shift" out of gear.

This is a relatively easy and inexpensive repair.  I usually replace ALL of the mounts, unless some others have been replaced recently.